# How to install Android Market App on the emulator?

Tags: android, google-play

I am not able to access android market through emulator.

Comment: This one is solved, but see also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5985679/app-missing-in-the-android-market).

Answer (score 24):

I got Android Market to work on Emulator for Platform 2.3 using OS 10.6.6:

First download and setup emulator on your mac. 
Launch emulator and create an AVD. I created one called `vd1`. 
Close `vd1`.

Launch Terminal in Utilities and enable the Finder to show hidden system files and folders by executing following commands:

```
lsy$ defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE
lsy$ killall Finder
```

Download `system.img`
http://www.mediafire.com/?s8eeph3r71ho1lz

Copy system.img to two locations:

```
[username]\.android\avd\[vd1]\
[username]\android\platforms\android-9\images\
```

Launch emulator from Terminal

```
lsy$ cd android\tools
lsy$ ./emulator -avd [vd1] -partition-size 100
```

Comment: Any solution to the missing apps problem?

Comment: For some reason, under this option the Market displays less apps than in the pankaj's answer.

Comment: Please do not advocate software piracy on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 9):

Android Market is not available through the emulator for similar reasons it is not available through the developer phone.  Allowing people to buy applications with an unlocked phone (or the emulator) would make it easier for those paid apps to be redistributed as freee apps.

Comment: Why not distributed a Android Market showing only the free apps with the emulator, just like the Market available for most people outside of US?

Comment: Sounds like a good recommendation for the Google/T-Mobile folks.

Comment: The market is not available through the emulator, but it IS available on the G1 developer phone.

Answer (score 7):

Will's right. But also see this if it helps: http://forum.openhandsetdevelopers.com/running-android-market-on-emulator-no-download-issue-t82.html

Answer (score 3):

Check out this link.

http://tech-droid.blogspot.com/2009/11/android-market-on-emulator.html

You get a full featured market on your emulator. I don't know if it's
legal(allowed by Google), but the image file, that this post mentions,
is a link to HTC's download page.

I am able to access all the market apps now, right from the emulator,
the paid ones, and the copy-protected ones also.

Cheers.

Dexter.

Comment: Please do not advocate software piracy on StackOverflow.

Comment: CommonsWare, I want Google Play on emulator to test whether intents work with all the major apps. I need Google Maps, and on another emulator I need Bing Maps. On a third I need both (what happens when both are present?) And there are various email apps, and so on and so forth. My desire to install from Google Play has nothing to do with software piracy, and it has been obvious to me from the way they ask the questions that nobody on Stack Overflow is planning to hoist the Jolly Roger.

Answer (score 3):

The emulator does not have the Android Market. The Android Market is only available for devices whose manufacturers have licensed the Android Market from Google.

Answer (score 2):

Android Studio from version 2.3.2 has [Google Play System Images](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2017/04/google-play-system-images-android.html).
You are able to create the simulator with the Play Store (old name: Android Market App).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use this test framework : [android-test-billing](http://code.google.com/p/android-test-billing) to test the In-App billing on the emulator.
This library was used in the project Horer - [horaires de RER](http://www.horer.fr).

Answer (score 0):

I have did it in my 1.6 emulator it worked fine , Try this,

1. Download system.img from following link
   http://www.4shared.com/get/x6pZm3-W/system.html
2. Go to avd folder. It will be in your c drive probably
   ( example C:\Documents and Settings\Vadivelan.android\avd\market.avd)
3. Paste the download file
4. Now launch the emulator
   Market is ready

But am not sure it will work in 2.2 emulator, because the given system.img file is specific to 1.6. For 2.2 download the 2.2 system.img (but i doubt it works, as per my information it gives error)

Regards,
Vadivelan

Answer (score 0):

just find the same app from a trusted website that allows you to download the .apk file to launch the app without using the play store. You wont be able to find all apps, but most of them should be relatively easy to find and download without using the play store.