# In-app billing in Android - questions

Tags: android, google-play, billing

I have several questions about the Android in-app billing, as I cannot find what I need in the documentation.

1: It does require Android 1.6 or higher, AND Market 2.3 or higher. How can I install Android Market 2.3 manually, if  the device I have is NOT rooted?

2: I tried it on Android 2.2 and Market version 2.2.11, but there were errors in reading Bundle responses.

3: Does it even have a chance running on emulator?

4: What do I actually have to do, to test in-app purchase? I downloaded the sample app, and compiled it, but I could not even get my static responses back (Market app 2.2.11).

5: Actually, is it LEGAL to install the Android Market 2.3 on devices with lower Api Level? Google say you need Droid 1.6 SDK, and market 2.3, but as far as I know there are no (or very few) devices with Market 2.3 that are running below 2.3 Android. Can you update your Market app?

6: (Lame) Does the Android Market Client auto update itself, when I new one is released ?

Comment: Most of the answers to this question are now outdated. People should look for more recent information, since the latest in-app billing version, IAB3, is significantly different from the one available at the time these answers were posted.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/index.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. You shouldn't have to install Market 2.3.0 manually, the market app should update itself when a new version is released.
2. You already said it requires Market 2.3.0 so obviously it won't work on 2.2.11.
3. Lots of people have been running Market on the emulator, so it may work: [How to install Android Market App on the emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387830/does-the-android-market-work-on-the-emulator)
4. See question 2.  Also even if you have Market 2.3.0 I'm not sure Google have enabled the testing phase yet.  I too would like to use in app purchases but I'm not going to bother trying it for a few months.
5. I believe all devices will get Market 2.3.0, not just those running Android 2.3, since it's just an app and not part of the OS, but I could be wrong.
6. Yes.

Comment: It sucks right now, It will give you very hard time. Give them time to screw those guys who are project leads of in-app billing because doc is very very vague. They describe every thing about the inner architecture (which usually we don't want to know) and they don't bother to tell the very important information about how it works. They provided an example that really sucks and is very very complicated. They put all the classes under one head Service... and it really sucks in debugging.

Comment: I know the doc is vague so I tried to make a simpler tutorial: http://blog.blundell-apps.com/simple-inapp-billing-payment/