# Force Close trying to launch a market page from and alert box

Tags: android

Can anyone figure out why this causes a force close??

```
void failbox(){
     // Create the alert box
       AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

       // Set the message to display
       alertbox.setMessage(R.string.fail);

       alertbox.setPositiveButton("Get Busybox", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

           // do something when the button is clicked
           public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {


               Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);  
               i.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=stericson.busybox"));
           }
           });

       // set a negative/no button and create a listener
       alertbox.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

           // do something when the button is clicked
           public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

           }
       });

        // show the alert box
       alertbox.show();

   }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the context of "this" ... mouse over it.  Is this inside an activity?

Comment: I am sadly a little confused by your question... haha. Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting the forced close in the emulator, that's just how it is, as best I can tell.  You cannot access the market through the market app from an emulator.

Does your app still crash when run on a *real* Android device?

(Of course, some folks have figured out sneaky ways to get to the market from an emulator.  See [How to install Android Market App on the emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387830/does-the-android-market-work-on-the-emulator))