# App missing in the Android Market

Tags: android, google-play

I recently installed the Market App on the Android Emulator (in a virtual device with Android 2.2), but when I search for the Wikitude app it didn't appear! The webpage of the market lists it, but it doesn't appear on the emulator (other apps does).

Does anyone know why this happens and/or how to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Guidance how to enable the Market on the emulator is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387830/how-to-install-android-market-app-on-the-emulator). Depending on the method used, the Market displays different subsets of apps, and it has nothing to do with OS version.

Comment: The Market is not supposed to run in the Emulator since it would allow priating apps. You are moving into a legal gray area.

Comment: have you tried the access directly using a market://details?id=com.insightoverflow.getFocused_offline like link? I mean, to check if it goes this way at least ?

Answer (score 5):

Some apps don't show in the Android Market based off device capability.  There may be a device hardware feature you're not emulating, causing the Market not to show the Wikitude app.

Comment: I thought that too, but I checked and added every requirement for Wikitude to the virtual device and the app still didn't appear on the Market...

Answer (score 3):

I've had issues with specific devices when I had the "Copy Protection" flag enabled when publishing the app.  Disabling this feature made the app appear in the Market app on the device.

Answer (score 1):

Some apps does not shows through market app if that application contains market filter options like the one that is mentioned on the link below: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/market-filters.html.

```
  <supports-screens android:resizeable=["true"| "false"]
                      android:smallScreens=["true" | "false"]
                      android:normalScreens=["true" | "false"]
                      android:largeScreens=["true" | "false"]
                      android:xlargeScreens=["true" | "false"]
                      android:anyDensity=["true" | "false"]
                      android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="integer"
                      android:compatibleWidthLimitDp="integer"
                      android:largestWidthLimitDp="integer"/>
```

If any one of these filter options is provided in the Android manifest.xml file then the applications will be filtered on the market app while we searching and only the device that meet required features will only be shown/listed. But on the mean time if you search through the web browser the application will be listed. Market filters, filters the app only from the Android market app and not while browsing through a browser. For an example: if an applications mainfest.xml contains :

```
 <supports-screens android:smallScreens="false" android:normalScreens="true"
     android:largeScreens="true"/>
```

Then that application will be shown only while we are searching from a device of screen sizes that come under normal and large. This application will not be listed if we are searching from a device that comes under small screen sizes. And  if we search the same app on browser it will be listed. Kindly check if that condition is preventing the app to be listed.

Comment: You haven't mentioned the emulator even once. Have you ever seen it? The emulator emulates (by default) a med-screen device with mdpi or hdpi - your typical smartphone. The apps that work on it have no problem detecting that. Still, the Market selection is way crippled compared to a real phone with similar specs. If this question had an easy answer straight from the docs, there won't be a bounty.

Answer (score 1):

The emulator is not a valid device. Have you installed Market by some workaround? Like getting the APK on the emulator.
Market allows only for listed and registered phones - check the view devices section in the Market Admin. Since there is no Emulator phone, it will not be shown :)

Comment: The workarounds for that are listed all over the 'Net. See [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387830/how-to-install-android-market-app-on-the-emulator), for example.

Answer (score 0):

Which contry/region are you from? We did experience the same "apps missing" issue in China until last Thursdy, 06/09/2011. Our apps seem disppearing stranglely from Android Market client on mobile phones. Finally,we just tries to refresh the "save" button for each app in our Android developer account. And it seems to work... 
some more information that could help, 
1. this kind of "save" button solution works for Android OS 2.2 and above 
2. for Android OS 2.1, we did not have our apps missing issue
since we have seen in forums some other developers suffering from the same issue recently, we have written an article about it, hoping that could help.
http://xmscan.wordpress.com/2011/06/10/android-market-app-missing-issue/

Comment: The emulator is set up by default as en-US. I even changed the GPS coordinates to something plausible.

Answer (score 0):

If the developer of the application is using "Copy Protection" there can be issues.  From what I understand, Google white-lists certain hardware-software combinations for "Copy Protection" applications.  For example, shortly after I received the Froyo update on my Samsung Captivate I could not see any "Copy Protection" apps because Google had not white-listed the new Froyo ROM yet.  That said, I highly doubt that the emulator is on the white-list.

Comment: Can one see if the app has the protection flag without downloading? I know there are secondary Market mirrors out there, like AppBrain... Maybe there's one that lists this kind of data?