# see all apps in market in the emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, google-play

It is possible to install android market on android 2.x in the emulator. But I have read that many can´t see any apps or very few. 
Is it possible to see the hole market or at least the free apps and install them? Have any achieved this? If it possible, how is it done?

Comment: possible duplicate of [App missing in the Android Market](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5985679/app-missing-in-the-android-market)

Comment: Guidance how to enable Market on the emulator is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387830/how-to-install-android-market-app-on-the-emulator).