# android Facebook Error: Unable to login in to fb app

Tags: android

While working on my fb app I found a message in webview and not able to get in to login page

*"Sorry, something went wrong. We’re working on getting this fixed as soon as we can..."*

While app was working f9 a day before....

I don't know why I'm unable to get the login screen of fb.

Does anyone knows solution to my problem.

[image]

With Regards,

Arpit Garg

Comment: Well Problem is generally In case we have chaged some settings say Hash key or other from our account settings and the chages were not reflected in time on the fb end,, In my case I chaged the Hash key as some wrong value... And it was unable to update... Then Finally I re-modifed key from settings and then commit the settings successfully. The work was done

Comment: http://gnuc.in/resources/archives/1541

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6550285/what-api-is-used-by-google-android-app

Answer (score 0):

Facebook is probably off-line due to technical adjustments.

Try again in a few moments.

Comment: @Arpit, if an answer does not solve your problem, you should not be accepting it.