# Can I use android apps on my pc?How?

Tags: android

Friends

From one of my friend I heard that we can use android apps on our pc...

Can I use Android Apps on my laptop?

And If yes,please tell me How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can

[Run Mobile Apps on PC:](http://bluestacks.com/)

But this will support only Windows or Mac. Not on **linux** OS

Answer (score 0):

You need an android emulator for that. You can look for a standalone emulator or download the android SDK for eclipse and you'll have some too.

Here is another thread speaking of how to install the market on the emulator:

[How to install Android Market App on the emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387830/how-to-install-android-market-app-on-the-emulator)

Answer (score 0):

Install BlueStack by AMD. 
[Bluestacks web page](http://bluestacks.com/).
This works on Intel Based Windows machines also. I have not tried it on Mac.

Answer (score 0):

You can install a virtual machine like VMWare or VirtualBox to run Android in your PC. Example: http://www.kirsle.net/blog/kirsle/android-4-0-in-virtualbox

Comment: ok,thanks I'll try this also.....